# How to fourier transform of this random distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

I want to calculate characteristic function of this probability density function (PDF) of $X$.
The distribution of $X$ is given by the following equation:

$$ f_{X}(x)=\frac{\beta}{\alpha\Gamma(1/\beta)}\ x \ e^{-\left( |x^{2}-\mu| / \alpha  \right)^{\beta}} $$

where $\alpha, \beta \ $  and  $ \mu \  $ are constant and lager than zero. Random variable $ x $ also larger than zero.

I tried calculation of characteristic function of $X$. But that is so complicated. How can I get this characteristic function?